# not getting email id with linkedin swift

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I created app on linked in with full permission and I using following url but still I not getting email address.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline,picture-url,public-profile-url)?format=json

```
if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {
        LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest(url, success: { (response) -> Void in
            print(response?.data ?? "")
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123347/getting-email-address-from-linkedin-api